# Divs that are floated left are overlapping. I dont want them to overlap

Tags: css, html, tags

I want to be able to float divs one, two and fin and at the same time have them not overlap upon the other. Right now as it is set up, when I have a look at it on a smaller screen, fin lands on top on top of two and two on top of fin.

Any kind of help in this direction will be appreciated.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="iwrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <center>
    <div id="i1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="img-tag">The BALD DESIGNER Look</span>
   </div>
   </center>
 </div>
 <div class="two">
 <center>
   <div id="i2">
   </div>
   <div>
     <span class="img-tag">Meet TECHNODEN- My Home Design Space</span>
   </div>
 </center>
 </div>

<div class="fin">
   <a href="http://www.vrohit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Resume_RohitVairamohan.pdf" target="_blank">Grab my Resume</a>
   <div class="descpt">Facts about Me</div><div style="font-size: 90%; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.7em;" > 
   > I love to go hiking and on adventure trails. This helps me often think of adventurous and innovative solutions to critical problems.
   > Being a trained classical singer, I introduce new rhythm into my designs. 
   > I am good at finding an organization among my disorganized belongings and this helps me be clinical and find patterns during my research.
   > And Yes, you may have guessed it by now; my favorite color is Green.
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear12fin"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS associated with it:

```
.clear12fin{
clear: both;
}

.iwrapper {
width:99%;
}

#i1{background-image:url("http://www.vrohit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/my-picg.png");
width:300px; /*image width*/
height:300px; /*image height*/
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

#i1:hover{background-image:url("http://www.vrohit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/my-pic.png");}

#i2{background-image:url("http://www.vrohit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/designspaceg.png");
width:300px; /*image width*/
height:300px; /*image height*/
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

#i2:hover{background-image:url("http://www.vrohit.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/designspace.png");}



.one{float:left; width:32%; margin-right:1%;}
.two{float:left; width:32%; margin-right:1%;}
.fin{display:inline-block; width:33%;
}
```

Comment: If you add `div {overflow: hidden}` they won't overlap (but the images will be clipped).

Comment: You can try it in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Sw38u/)

Comment: did u try giving float:left to fin ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a min-width on `.iwrapper`

CSS

```
.iwrapper {
    width:99%;
    min-width: 930px; /* image width plus 30px for a 10px margin between divs*/   
}
```

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/8RyXu/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the @media query to make your page responsive... you can set the positioning of the elements based on the screen size by using @media in your css.. if you need help with that, let me know..

Comment: Yes would love your input on how to do that. Pardon my ignorance, I am new to HTML/ CSS

Comment: hey check out this [tutorial on @media in css](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/). this should be a great starting point if you are new to media query.

Comment: here's a fiddle for what i believe you are wanting to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/64Jpf/.. Any screen size that is less than 760px width will make you div's display one below the other, thereby avoiding the overlapping problem. Hope this helps.